# WebDriver FirefoxDriver Selenium download arquivo

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium-webdriver

Estou automatizando o download de um arquivo `.xlsx` de um site com `Selenium` com o `FirefoxDriver` mas não consigo interagir no pop-up de download do site!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tem como eu interagir com o pop-up marcando Salvar arquivo e enviar para uma pasta?

Estou utilizando o seguinte código para interferir no pop-up:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Url = "";

            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
           driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class='jss174']")).Click();

            Thread.Sleep(6000);

            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@class='jss314']")).Click();

            Thread.Sleep(6000);

            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//img[@src='a95fbd8f692090fb308a787688c0373f.png']")).Click();

            FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

            profile.AcceptUntrustedCertificates = true;           

            profile.SetPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);

            profile.SetPreference("browser.download.dir", "c:\\mydownloads");

            //profile.SetPreference("network.http.phishy-userpass-length", 255);
            profile.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);

            profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/excel");
```

E estou obtendo o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você não vai conseguir fazer isso com essa janela. Pq ela é do Windows e o selenium se limita ao browser. Você pode tentar criar uns `options` para salvar em um diretório específico

Comment: @Tmilitino dá para editar as opções do navegador para fazer download automaticamente em um diretório. Mas quando reabre o navegador com o FirefoxDriver as configurações não se mantem!

Comment: @Tmilitino obrigado pelas dicas! Troquei o WebDriver para o ChromeDriver, e consegui o download automático na pasta padrão Downloads!